# Need Assistance in Simple iMacros Programming

Tags: javascript, automation, imacros, extract

Lets be straightforward.

I want to extract ONLY the link of product on this page,
https://www.tokopedia.com/p/fashion-aksesoris/aksesoris/ikat-pinggang

I am using iMacros browser v10 and using extraction feature to target HREF attribute.. But it's not working. Maybe because it's javascript event triggered. And I don't know how to solve this, what to code..

Any help will be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following code:

```
SET !LOOP 1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"product-card ng-scope" EXTRACT=HTM
SET productLink EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/a href=\"(.*?)\"/)[1];")
'PROMPT {{productLink}}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks the answer. But I copy and pasted it but not working. It returns me an error. Sorry anyway for this confusion.

Comment: TypeError: "#EANF#".match(...) is null, line 9 (Error code: -1001)

Anyway I thought you may be joking. How you could get the class "product-card ng-scope", and also what every line of those imacros code means? Can you give comments? Really I was really annoying for this. @[Shugar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4270557/shugar)

Comment: The code I provided in fact works good on the page which you indicated in the question. Does the error appear when you play the macro in usual (not loop) mode? (Uncomment the last line to see the result and, if you play it in loop mode, set the 'Max' value to 24.) Also it may be useful for you to read [the wiki](http://wiki.imacros.net/Main_Page). There you can really get the best comments.